# How do I install three desktops?

Tags: desktop-environments

In lubuntu I could add desktops. I don't see that in Ubuntu. I am using the default installed Ubuntu.

Thank you;

Sherman

Answer (score 2):

I found it so this is closed. I went to system settings and modified the appearance. My apologies.

Sherman